# Microsoft.Reporting - how to get it?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting

I have Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition.

In that edition i have access to Microsoft.Reporting and additional i have some report design tools integrated with VS IDE.

How to get that tools and class, if im now using Visual Studio 2012 Express?

I need this for Windows Forms applications, not for Web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes with Sql Server Reporting Services

Comment: Can i download them separately, or i have to download SQL Server Express with Advanced Services?

Comment: Yes, it comes together with Sql Server as part of the product. You need to download the whole package.

Comment: I downloaded it, i installed it, but there is no tool for report design in Visual Studio 2012. I have "ReportViewer" control now, but it has no "choose report" or "design new report" :(

Comment: Those toools are only available in non free versions.. What you get for free is that :(

Comment: You mean non-free SQL Server, or non-free Visual Studio?

Comment: Non free Sql. Reporting Service is part of Sql Server package. But look what I just saw: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6116

Comment: I saw it. This is not what im looking for. It does not integrate with any VS. It was so cool in VS2008... Thanks for your help Oscar. Looks like i have to fight with pixels if i need .NET 4.x

Comment: Well, you can download a trial version of Sql Enterprise, valid for 180 days..
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8850
Good lock!